# Hilt dependency injection for UI testing says "HiltAndroidRule" wasn't added but it was

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use Hilt for dependency injection but it gives the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.` The HiltAndroidRule is added though:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@UninstallModules(ItemsModule.class)
@HiltAndroidTest
public class SelectItemActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public HiltAndroidRule hiltRule = new HiltAndroidRule(this);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        hiltRule.inject();
    }
    @BindValue
    List<Item> items = getItems();
    List<Item> getItems()  {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(1, "Item1", "", true, true, true));;
        items.add(new Item(2, "Item2", "", true, true, true));;
        items.add(new Item(3, "Item3", "", true, true, true));;
        return items;
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SelectItemActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(SelectItemActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void text_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withText("Item1")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding an ItemsModule inside the class but that had the same result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must wrap it using `RuleChain` or by applying `order` parameter to the `Rule` Annotation.

It is explained in detail here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#multiple-testrules

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same error when I was trying to test an activity that was not the launcher one. I am using Kotlin, but something very similar should apply to Java.

Let's say you want to test `MyActivity`. First you need to define your `ActivityTestRule` as a not launch activity:

```kotlin
val targetContext: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

@get:Rule(order = 0) 
var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@get:Rule(order = 1) 
var testRule = ActivityTestRule(MyActivity::class.java, false, false)
```

And then, launch your activity, after hilt injection:

```
@Before fun setup() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    testRule.launchActivity(Intent(targetContext, MyActivity::class.java))
}
```

Comment: where does targetContext come from?

Comment: @JeffreyLiu I have updated my answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks, for me the "order" was red in IDE, can you tell us the gradle detail? like junit version, etc.

Comment: @JeffreyLiu [check this out](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#multiple-testrules). The order annotation is available in JUnit version 4.13 or higher.

Comment: yeah, but not working for me... i have 4.13